# Fn::GetAtt for exported resource/stack

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless

Is it possible to use the logicalId of an exported stack. I've created an APIGateway resource and exported it. It's logicalId is `rApiGatewayVehRestApi`. When I try fetching the RootResourceId of `rApiGatewayVehRestApi`, I get the below error during serverless deployment:

`The CloudFormation template is invalid: Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource rApiGatewayVehRestApi`

Below is the snippet of serverless config:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  stage: dev
  region: ${self:custom.pRegion}
  memorySize: 1024
  timeout: 30
  apiGateway: 
    restApiId: 
      "Fn::ImportValue": ${self:custom.pOwner}-${self:custom.pEnvironment}-rApiGatewayVehRestApi
    restApiRootResourceId:
      Fn::GetAtt: [ rApiGatewayVehRestApi, RootResourceId ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you're getting that error is that no resource exists in the stack with the Logical ID `rApiGatewayVehRestApi`.

When you export a value, you are exporting a single value, not the whole resource. If you wanted to export the ID you could do the `Fn::GetAtt` on the exporting side, like:

```
Outputs:
  RestApiRootResourceId:
    Value: !GetAtt YourApiGateway.RootResourceId
    Export:
      Name: rApiGatewayVehRestApiId
```

A few notes on restrictions with Export as noted in the [Outputs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) documentation.

- Names of Exports can't use Ref or GetAtt functions
- Names of Imports can't use Ref or GetAtt functions